# Installing Software using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get things configured to push software installs & patches through powershell. I have already created a GP to enable WinRM.  I am able to connect to my test VM using `enter-pssession -computername computer -credential username` without any issues.  However, I am getting error message when i try to use the following command to install software `invoke-command -computername computername -command {c:\software\setup.exe}`

I am new to powershell.  I could be using the wrong command to install the software.  I have already been copied the file to the test VM.    Any assistance would be appreciate

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting AccessDenied, PSSessionStateBroken

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the fact that you missed the variable character '$' to 'computername'.

I never seen the '-command' ever being used in an Invoke-Command so I cannot comment about that.

Also, you could use Start-Process to run your .exe maybe?